# How to access a variable present in a scriptlet tag in some other scriptlet tag in JSP?

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

if i do this, it says "cannot find symbol:x". Is there anyway i can access x outside that scriptlet tag?

```
<%
String x="abc";
%>
<%
System.out.println(x);
%>
```

Comment: are both of those scriptlets in the same jsp?

Comment: yes, both the scriptlets are in same JSP. @int21h

Comment: I'm not sure how it doesn't work for you.  It works fine for me.  I can see why it wouldn't if the two are in separate JSPs but should work fine in 1.

Comment: @int21h Thanks for hearing out my problem.

Comment: Are you sure you do not want `out.println(x)` => goes in response instead of `System.out.println(x)` => goes on server console or log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access x by expression tag(<%= %>). You can try the following code :

```
<%
String x="abc";
%>
<%=x %>
```